# Rotating Blockquote from Mysql DB C#

Tags: c#, jquery, mysql, blockquote

Here's my DB

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `comments` (
  `com_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `com_name` varchar(500) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `com_content` text CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `com_website` varchar(500) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  `com_date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`com_id`)
)
```

Here's my Front End

```
<link href="js/jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
 <div class="container">
    <asp:Label ID="lblComment" runat="server" Text=""/>
</div>
<script src="js/jquery.bxslider.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
            mode: 'horizontal',
            slideMargin: 3,
            auto: true
        });
    });
</script>
```

And Finally here's my Back End

```
private void dispComments()
{
    using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;database=test;uid=root;password="))
    {
        string query = "select * from comments order by com_date desc";
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        using (MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(query, conn))
        {
            da.Fill(dt);

            string comment = null;

            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                //Message title
                //news += "<div class='page-header' style='text-transform:capitalize;'><small>";
                //news += dt.Rows[i]["com_content"].ToString();
                //news +="</small></div>";

                //Message Body
                comment += "<ul class='bxslider'>";
                comment += "<li>";
                comment += "<blockquote>";
                comment += dt.Rows[i]["com_content"].ToString();
                comment += "<p style='text-align: right; margin-right: 20px;'>";
                comment += dt.Rows[i]["com_name"].ToString();
                comment += "</p></blockquote>";
                comment += "</li>";
                comment += "</ul>";

            }
            lblComment.Text = comment;
        }
    }
}
```

...I have 3 comments on my comments table, all three of 'em are displayed and the output is fine except they tend to appear individually, only one comment to display per rotation. Where have i gone wrong? Please help!!

Comment: It would be helpful if you would start your question with the actual question, so that the users would understand what all of this code is you're throwing at them. As it is now, you have to skip to the end, read the question and go back to read the code...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `<ul>` should be outside the `for` loop. The current code is creating a new `<ul>` under every iteration. So for each `li` you have a `ul`, and for each `ul` the slider is initialised.

Modify to this code,

```
string comment = null;
comment += "<ul class='bxslider'>";
for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    comment += "<li>";
    ....
    comment += "</li>";
}
comment += "</ul>";
```